# Can I know which page is getting rendered in the _Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am sorry if this question was asked before, I wasn't able to find anything.
I have a piece of content/module that needs to be displayed differently on the lading page than on all other pages of the website. It goes like this:

HOMEPAGE:

```
 ______________________________
|    _________      ________   |
|   |         |    |        |  |
|   |   1     |    |    2   |  |
|   |_________|    |________|  |
|______________________________|
```

All OTHER pages:

```
 ______________________________
|                   ________   |
|                  |        |  |
|                  |    2   |  |
|                  |________|  |
|______________________________|
```

The only way I could think of solving this...is if I could build a toggle in the _Layout to display Box1 only when the homepage is getting rendered

My question is:

1. Any way of knowing which page going to get rendered from the Layout, if not:
2. (if not) is there another way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple layout pages.

Just create your secondary layout, then in your Landing page reference this layout with the following at the top (after your @model statement)

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLandingLayout.cshtml"; }
```

Comment: This is a much better solution, the layout most likely should not be doing logic to determine how it needs to display.